# Linq query to check for two values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to using linq to query the database and just wonder if my query has any flaws, because it does not act as I want. I just wnat to check if there excist any items in the database that match two numbers.

If yes, nothing should be added to the database, but it seems like it continue to add new stuff despite I make a check if an item already excist with this numbers! What have i done wrong and how can I improve my query?

```
        if(db.Member.Any(x => x.ID == c && x.CountryID == d))
        {
            Do something if there is a match and the member already excist in DB...
        } else
        {
          Write new Member to DB....  
        }
```

Comment: Are `c` and `d` both `int` or what type ?

Comment: @Sampath yes, they are both INT

Comment: It would seem that you're not supplying c or d with values that exist in your database. How do you calculate these values? And why do you have a field called 'ID' which does not uniquely identify a record (since you include countryID in the query). Does Any() return true if only one of these fields is supplied?

Comment: @TonPlooij The value C and D are parameters to the Controller method.

Comment: I would think there's something wrong with these. If you change the c and d parms to hardcoded values (e.g. x.ID == 10 && x.CountryID == 12) that exist in your database, does it then work as expected?

Comment: @TonPlooij I hardcoded the values and it still add new items! It's very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this version too.

```
var memberObject=db.Member.Where(x => x.ID == c && x.CountryID == d).FirstOrDefault();

if (memberObject==null){
  //Write new Member to DB....  
}else{
  //Do something if there is a match and the member already excist in DB...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still add new items to the DB!?

Comment: Then you don't have such values on your particular record.Otherwise how can it be happened.Can you share the record which you try to find out ? may be table row image or something like that.

Comment: It's working now! I made a typing error when I copy/pasted your code! Thanks for the help!